# What does the center function do in this program?

Tags: c++, opencv

I got this program from https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2017/01/28/eyeball-tracking-for-mouse-control-in-opencv/, and while I think the program is easy to understand, I have a few problems understanding the code given, specifically the "center" function that this program uses. I have googled about "center" function for OpenCV and C++, and there are no results regarding the function. Here's the code from the site given:

```
cv::Vec3f getEyeball(cv::Mat &eye, std::vector<cv::Vec3f> &circles)
{
  std::vector<int> sums(circles.size(), 0);
  for (int y = 0; y < eye.rows; y++)
  {
      uchar *ptr = eye.ptr<uchar>(y);
      for (int x = 0; x < eye.cols; x++)
      {
          int value = static_cast<int>(*ptr);
          for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
          {
              cv::Point center((int)std::round(circles[i][0]),
                               (int)std::round(circles[i][1]));
              int radius = (int)std::round(circles[i][2]);
              if (  std::pow(x - center.x, 2)
                  + std::pow(y - center.y, 2) < std::pow(radius, 2))
              {
                  sums[i] += value;
              }
          }
          ++ptr;
      }
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`center` in your program is **not a function**, it is an **object name** for **template type `Point()`** in OpenCV.

As it is a user-defined name, you can change the name from `center` to any valid variable name.

Basically, what this snippet:

```
cv::Point center((int)std::round(circles[i][0]),
                               (int)std::round(circles[i][1]));
```

does is, it stores x coordinate `(int)std::round(circles[i][0])` and y coordinate `(int)std::round(circles[i][1])` in the `Point` object named as `center`.

Detailed documentation of `Point` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d4e/classcv_1_1Point__.html)

Now, by `center.x` and `center.y`, you can extract the x and y coordinates stored in the `Point` object named `center`, respectively.

Comment: Makes sense. I usually initialize object names with capital letters, so it throws me off when somebody uses small letters for it instead. Also, I was a bit unfamiliar with object initialization on C++, since I use Java more often. Thanks!